# Would you put data access in an Azure Worker Role?

Tags: data-access-layer, asp.net-web-api2, azure-worker-roles, azure-table-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 5 app that will run on Azure. I'm using DocumentDb and Azure Table Storage for managing my data.

I'm thinking about moving my DAL functions to an Azure Worker Role that I call from my web role using HTTP -- not message queue.

I think, typically, worker roles are used for time-insensitive back-end jobs but I see no reason why I couldn't move my DAL to a worker role that responds to HTTP requests. I think this would give me nice separation for my data layer and pretty easy way to scale up/out.

This is making even more sense to me ever since I switched to DocumentDb and Azure Table Storage that require some extra work handling data. I thought a worker role would be ideal for handling all that extra work as it can scale up much more easily.

Anyway, I wanted to get others' suggestions and perspective on this. Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worker roles do not have IIS, which is why they are normally used in conjunction with message queues.  If you want your DAL to be a Web API for example then just use another Web role.

Comment: Is hosting the DAL as a Web API in a web role a common approach? Would calling my Web API -- from one web role to another --  create any slow down in my application? I've never thought of Web API for internal consumption. I've always thought of it for mobile clients or external parties. Seems logical. Just want to understand if it's a good approach.

Comment: I assumed by "role that responds to HTTP requests" you meant a Web API, but the answer applies to anything communicating over HTTP.  You can use the internal endpoints to communicate between roles to help reduce latency.